# how to configure 500 error page with Spring boot 2.5.2, the default set up not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am relying on spring boot to handle the 500 (Internal server error). Followed various links which mentioned that I could customize my web app using the below properties

```
server.error.path=/error
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

I also wrote my custom error page controller as:

```
@Controller
public class GlobalErrorController implements ErrorController {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);
        log.error("Error occurred!");
        if (status != null) {
            Integer statusCode = Integer.valueOf(status.toString());
            // handle all the 400 error codes
            if (statusCode != null && statusCode % 400 < 100) {
                return "error/4xx";
            } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()) {
                return "error/500";
            }
        }
        return "error/genericError";
    }

}
```

This controller is never being called and I only see the server error page with console errors as below:

[image]

I can see see the error is clearly being thrown with /error page in console. Below is part of the error log:

> 2021-07-27 16:13:28.769 ERROR 22040 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost]                  175 : Exception Processing
> ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

One thing to note here is that the exception is being thrown in the filter, because I was testing the behavior of the app when one of the service goes down. But I should have still gotten the page I was expecting with /error controller.

**Update:**
I did some further research and found that an exception thrown in filters would not be handled by global exception handler. In order to handle the exceptions by spring's exception handler I added this filter which catches the exceptions raised by any other filters. The code is below:

```java
@Component
public class ExceptionHandlerFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("handlerExceptionResolver")
    private HandlerExceptionResolver resolver;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            log.error("Spring Security Filter Chain Exception:", ex);
            resolver.resolveException(request, response, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

I also created a **exception handler** just for this as below:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
   
    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, RuntimeException ex) 
    {
       log.error("Request: " + req.getRequestURL() + " raised " + ex);

       ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("error/500");
       mav.addObject("exception", ex);
       mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
       return mav;
     }

}
```

Now the issue is that it just shows the blank page without any content. I was expecting to see my custom error page located at error/500.

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine for me. Could you change your class to below code and tell the result?

- `error_404` and `error_500` is custom html error pages.

```java
@Controller
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);

        if (status != null) {
            int statusCode = Integer.parseInt(status.toString());
            switch (statusCode) {
                case 404:
                    return "error_404";

                case 500:
                    return "error_500";
            }
        }
        return "error";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
server.error.path=/error
```

Comment: Thanks, the above code is not compatible with 2.5.2 as there is not getErrorPath in ErrorController interface anymore. In any case, I implemented the above code and it didn't work for me.

Comment: I didn't know that. Mine is v2.4.2.